# Filtering a list based on values of another list satisfying a condition

Tags: pandas, list, filter, list-comprehension

I have two list of lists as follows -

```
list1 = [[12,10,8],[20,8,15]]
list2 = [[15,15,15], [15,15,15]]
```

Now I want to sort list2 so that it will have values if individual lists in list 1 has values greater than 8 as an example. Therefore, for this case the filtered list2 will look something like -

```
filtered_list2 = [[15,15],[15,15]]
```

since 8 in both the lists of list1 will get filtered out. I tried list comprehension with no success. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to sort when `list2` has all same values? instead you can select elements by index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try for loop

```
l = [[v for t, v in zip(x, y) if t >8 ] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
Out[260]: [[15, 15], [15, 15]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.